# Windows machines with an 'Arial (W1)' font installed

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Has anyone ever come across this font? The standard Arial variants bundled with Windows are also present. I can't find any trace of a free or paid version of 'Arial (W1)' though.

Comment: Perhaps [this old post](http://openoffice.2283327.n4.nabble.com/W1-fonts-in-Writer-tp2898974p2898977.html) I found on a forum can shed some light - seems to suggest (W1) fonts were printer fonts held in ROM.  Where did you see this? In an ancient Word document perhaps?

Comment: A report layout definition file. Thanks